# Missing or invalid map id

Tags: android, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm working on my first ionic app as an intern, and I have this error that has been blocking me for a while.
The idea is to display a google map on the app, it works fine in the browser but it doesn't display on the phone.
"Error: Missing or invalid map id." is displayed in the console of the application on the phone, I checked my codes with tutorials, read a lot of sites.
Any idea ? I can get the coordinates of the markers on the map by clicking on the supposed location on the map.

Thanks a lot !

- AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="colentre.autourdemoi.map">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="colentre.autourdemoi.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="**********"/>

    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" /></manifest>
```

- Environment.ts

```
// This file can be replaced during build by using the `fileReplacements` array.
// `ng build` replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`.
// The list of file replacements can be found in `angular.json`.

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  mapsKey: '***************',
};

/*
 * For easier debugging in development mode, you can import the following file
 * to ignore zone related error stack frames such as `zone.run`, `zoneDelegate.invokeTask`.
 *
 * This import should be commented out in production mode because it will have a negative impact
 * on performance if an error is thrown.
 */
// import 'zone.js/plugins/zone-error';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

- home.page.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { ModalPage } from '../modal/modal.page';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@capacitor/geolocation';
import { CapacitorGoogleMaps } from '@capacitor-community/capacitor-googlemaps-native';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  template: `
  <capacitor-google-map #map></capacitor-google-map>
  <button (click)="createMap()">Create Map</button>
`,
styles: [
  `
    capacitor-google-map {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 275px;
      height: 400px;
    }
  `,
],
})
export class HomePage {
@ViewChild('map')
mapRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
map: GoogleMap;
  constructor( private modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

ionViewDidEnter(){
this.createMap();
}

async createMap(){
this.map = await GoogleMap.create({
  id: 'my-map',
    
    apiKey: '******************',
     
     element: this.mapRef.nativeElement,
     
    config: {
      center: {
        lat: 47.26667 ,
        lng:  -0.08333,
      },
      zoom: 6,
    }

});
this.addMarker();

}
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZslM4.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuh7g.jpg)

I tried differents API Keys, to rewrite the code, lauchned it on different emulators ...

Comment: In my case, the app id i give in cloud console is not valid with the app I trying to implement the map. Because I restricted the key, I change the app id with valid one. It was solved.